# ServiceBusReceiver.ReceiveMessagesAsync is throwing exceptions

Tags: azureservicebus

I am attempting to read the `BlobCreated` events from a service bus dead letter topic:

```cs
await using(ServiceBusClient serviceBusClient = new ServiceBusClient("xxxxx"))
{
    await using (ServiceBusReceiver receiver = serviceBusClient.CreateReceiver("TOPICNAME/Subscriptions/blob-events/$deadletterqueue"))
    {
        var messages = receiver.ReceiveMessagesAsync(cancellationToken);

        //Exception occurs in the enumeration
        await foreach(var message in messages)
        {
            //Process the message
        }
    }
}
```

The exception details:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000. (Parameter 'offset')
         at System.DateTimeOffset.ValidateDate(DateTime dateTime, TimeSpan offset)
         at System.DateTimeOffset..ctor(DateTime dateTime)
         at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Amqp.AmqpMessageConverter.AmqpMessageToSBMessage(AmqpMessage amqpMessage, Boolean isPeeked)
         at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Amqp.AmqpReceiver.ReceiveMessagesAsyncInternal(Int32 maxMessages, Nullable`1 maxWaitTime, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Amqp.AmqpReceiver.ReceiveMessagesAsyncInternal(Int32 maxMessages, Nullable`1 maxWaitTime, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Amqp.AmqpReceiver.<>c.<<ReceiveMessagesAsync>b__38_0>d.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusRetryPolicy.RunOperation[T1,TResult](Func`4 operation, T1 t1, TransportConnectionScope scope, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusRetryPolicy.RunOperation[T1,TResult](Func`4 operation, T1 t1, TransportConnectionScope scope, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Amqp.AmqpReceiver.ReceiveMessagesAsync(Int32 maxMessages, Nullable`1 maxWaitTime, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusReceiver.ReceiveMessagesAsync(Int32 maxMessages, Nullable`1 maxWaitTime, Boolean isProcessor, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusReceiver.ReceiveMessagesAsync(Int32 maxMessages, Nullable`1 maxWaitTime, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusReceiver.ReceiveMessageAsync(Nullable`1 maxWaitTime, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusReceiver.ReceiveMessagesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)+MoveNext()
         at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusReceiver.ReceiveMessagesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)+System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<System.Boolean>.GetResult()
         at CarMax.Online.Media.DlqMonitor.MonitorService.RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\git\CarMax\online-systems-media-dlq-monitor\src\CarMax.Online.Media.DlqMonitor\MonitorService.cs:line 98
         at CarMax.Online.Media.DlqMonitor.MonitorService.RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\git\CarMax\online-systems-media-dlq-monitor\src\CarMax.Online.Media.DlqMonitor\MonitorService.cs:line 98
```

The issue appears to be around the deserialization of the AMQP message from the wire. How can I get around this / prevent this exception from being thrown?

Note that I am able to poll this topic from legacy `.NET Framework 4.7.2` code using the old `WindowsAzure.ServiceBus` NuGet package.

Comment: Where the messages originate from? Are those created using custom code? Any chance to share a repro as a git repository?

Comment: Do you happen to have a stack trace with line numbers available?  Being able to see what line in the `AmqpMessageConverter` was triggering that exception would help to understand which attribute of the message was causing issues.

Comment: @JesseSquire - unfortunately the Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus 7.2.1 package doesn't include any debugging information.

Comment: @SeanFeldman - the messages originate from blob storage. An event is generated whenever a blob is created. Working on a repro.

Comment: Are you able to manually inspect one of the failing messages using the legacy package? It seems there is some issue in one of the fields that maps to the DateTimeOffset properties of ServiceBusReceivedMessage.

Comment: @RQDQ:  This seems like something that may require deeper investigation; would you be willing to open an issue in the [Azure SDK repository](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues) so that Josh and I are better able to assist?   That would allow us a better forum for discussion and sharing information so that we can dig into this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experienced this issue as well. It appears to be fixed in the pre-release Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus 7.3.0-beta

Discussion of the issue here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/23499